# python throws an error on different parts of the code as "invalid syntax"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, syntax-error

I'm writing code for my discord bot on discord.py. At one point, he began to give a "syntax invalid" error for everything, even if he hadn't done it before.
The last two versions of the code and errors:

```
@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash', 'money', 'bal', 'бал', 'баланс', 'деньги'])
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed( 
            title = f"""Баланс **{ctx.author}"""
            description = f"""Коины: **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM user WHERE id = {}").format(ctx.author.id).fetchone()[0]}** <:DS_SaphireCoin:1023242850483314710> \nОсколки Шизы:**{cursor.execute("SELECT shiza FROM user WHERE id = {}")}** <a:DS_shiza:1023239736061603864>"""
            timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
        ))
```

and

```
@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash', 'money', 'bal', 'бал', 'баланс', 'деньги'])
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed( 
            title = f"""Баланс **{ctx.author}"""
            description = f"""Коины: **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM user WHERE id = {}").format(ctx.author.id).fetchone()[0]}** <:DS_SaphireCoin:1023242850483314710>"""
            timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
        ))
```

in ver 1 error is

```
PS D:\Jeka\Chmonya bot>  d:; cd 'd:\Jeka\Chmonya bot'; & 'D:\Jeka\python\python.exe' 'c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '54767' '--' 'd:\Jeka\Chmonya bot\commands_user.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Jeka\python\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\Jeka\python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 320, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 294, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "d:\Jeka\Chmonya bot\commands_user.py", line 16
    description = f"""Коины: **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM user WHERE id = {}").format(ctx.author.id).fetchone()[0]}** <:DS_SaphireCoin:1023242850483314710> \nОсколки Шизы:**{cursor.execute("SELECT shiza FROM user WHERE id = {}").fetchone()[0]}** <a:DS_shiza:1023239736061603864>**"""
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in ver 2

```
PS D:\Jeka\Chmonya bot>  d:; cd 'd:\Jeka\Chmonya bot'; & 'D:\Jeka\python\python.exe' 'c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '54777' '--' 'd:\Jeka\Chmonya bot\commands_user.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Jeka\python\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\Jeka\python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 320, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "c:\Users\JeKa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 294, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "d:\Jeka\Chmonya bot\commands_user.py", line 16
    description = f"""Коины: **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM user WHERE id = {}").format(ctx.author.id).fetchone()[0]}** <:DS_SaphireCoin:1023242850483314710>"""
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i dunno how to fix it, pls help

Comment: Is the previous line (and current line) missing a trailing comma?

Comment: Maybe try not doing so much on one line.  A single misplaced `"` or `{` on that line will make the whole thing invalid, and it's going to be hard to spot exactly where the problem is.  Do your SQL queries in one statement each and format the string in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @quamrana said in his comment, I think you're missing a comma at the end of your function arguments.

```
@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash', 'money', 'bal', 'бал', 'баланс', 'деньги'])
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed( 
            title = f"""Баланс **{ctx.author}""",
            description = f"""Коины: **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM user WHERE id = {}").format(ctx.author.id).fetchone()[0]}** <:DS_SaphireCoin:1023242850483314710>""",
            timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
        ))
```

In general, for any function, the comma syntax is as below:

```
#Example
def hello_world(
                string = "something",
                other_string = "something else",
                x = 1):
    print(string, other_string, x)


hello world(string = "f",
            other_string = "y",
            x = 2)
```